# GoogleTV webview width is different than GoogleTV browser width

Tags: android, google-tv, television

I have an HTML5 TV web app that I wish to put in the GoogleTV Play Store. To do this, I needed to place the URL of the web app within a WebView. Everything works great this way, but I did noticed one oddity. When I view the app within GoogleTV's browser, the width is 1011px, but when the app is viewed within a WebView within a Play Store app, the width is 980px. Visually, the app takes up the same width on the screen.

I imagine what is going on is that the dpi is set differently and that is why the same visual width is indicating as being different pixel widths.

Is there a way to make the WebView PlayStore app to be the same amount of pixels wide (and high) as a web browser app?

Answer (score 0):

You may be having an issue with the auto zoom - it is on by default for Chrome on Google TV - try adding the following to your code:

```
<meta name="gtv-autozoom" content="off" />
```

Edit:
Have you considered creating an APK that just launches an Intent to Chrome which would then load your web app?